# Null Object Access error in system verilog

Tags: class, oop, system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to perform binary tree insertion and in order traversal in System Verilog using OOPs concepts. I am getting error that the object is being used before creating it. Please take a look at the code and help me if someone find any mistakes

```
class node;
  byte data;
  node left;
  node right;
  function new();
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  endfunction
endclass
class bin_search extends node;
  node newNode;
  node nd,root,current,parent;
  byte in_data;
  function new();
    super.new();
    this.in_data = in_data;
  endfunction
function automatic insert(in_data);
    newNode.data = nd.data;
    if(root.data == null) begin
      root = newNode;
      return;
    end
    else begin
      current = root;
      parent = null;
    end
    forever begin
      parent = current;
      if(in_data < current.data) begin
    current = current.left;
    if(current.left == null) begin
      parent.left = newNode;
      return;
    end
    end
  else begin
    current = current.right;
    if(current.right == null) begin
      parent.right = newNode;
      return;
    end
    end
    end
  endfunction
  function automatic inorder_traverse(node node_tr);
    //using nodes here
  endfunction
endclass

module binary;
  node NODE;
  bin_search bs;
  byte ins;

  initial begin
    NODE = new;
    bs = new;
    bs.insert(50);
    $display("Binary search tree after insertion:"); 
    bs.inorder_traverse(bs.root);
  end
endmodule
```

**Error message:**
Error-[NOA] Null object access
binary.sv, 28
The object at dereference depth 1 is being used before it was
constructed/allocated.
Please make sure that the object is allocated before using it.

Comment: your code does not show the mechanism of insertion which you complain about.  The message tells that you failed to check node references for 'null' somewhere in the recursion path (not shown in your  example).

Comment: BTW, there is no need to add the `automatic` keyword to your class methods; they always have automatic lifetimes.

Comment: Hi @Serge, Thankyou for the reply. I edited my function insert in the question. I cannot find where I am doing wrong. Please take a look at the edited question.

Answer (score -1):

The null error is thrown from the following line.

```
    newNode.data = nd.data;
```

I don't see neither `newNode` nor `nd` objects being constructed by calling `new()` either in constructor of `bin_search` class or in the `insert()` method itself.
You need to create objects of classes before accessing their members or methods.